# Open IE browser in Firefox/Chrome page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

Our Web application is based on IE9, which means only IE9 can open the pages in our site. We'll prevent user to browse our site when their browser is not IE9. 
But sometimes we had to send a link to user's email box to complete some actions and they will open the link directly with their default browser, the problem is here, if the default browser is not IE9 then they can't open the link, they have to copy the link to IE9. Our user don't want do this manually, they want open the link in IE9 directly no matter what the default browser is.

I have tried using ActiveXObject, but it only works in IE. I want have a script which can open IE browser in Firefox/Chrome page.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Flash, does it can execute command in client page?

Comment: "Our Web application is based on IE9" = I think I found the problem.

Comment: You can [create a protocol handler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41749105/725866)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have a link in an email that activates a *specific* program on the user's computer rather than the program that they've identified should be used (e.g., their default browser). I don't believe you can do that.

You can install "protocol handlers" in both Chrome and Safari (I suspect Firefox as well), which would let you send a link like `ie://example.com/path/to/app`. Your protocol handler would launch IE and take you to the relevant site. (Apple does this with iTunes.) But your users would have to install the handler (and, of course, you'd have to write it).

An easier answer might be to have the users install any of the ubiquitous "open in IE" add-ons/extensions that exist for Chrome, Firefox, etc. They follow the link, then choose "open in IE" from some kind of menu. (If they're using webmail, they may even be able to right-click the link and choose that line item, depending on the extension.)

---

Side note: Obviously, though, barring it being impossible I'd recommend making your application compatible with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Hi T.J., How can I write such a handler?!

Comment: @Hosein: I haven't done it, I just know it can be done. Shouldn't be hard to find information on it with searching.

Comment: I did search. for almost a whole day! but didn't find out how to write a handler to open a link in Google Chrome with IE. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I have application only runs on IE. Currently if user open my page on chrome means, it will throw alert. But may be i want js code where user clicks href or link where user can open IE from chrome? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5):

No you can't do it..

but there is some alternatives:

1. Install your users IE tab:
   FireFox - http://lifehacker.com/135297/internet-explorer-in-a-firefox-tab?tag=softwarewebpublishing,
   Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd
2. Use a batch file that will launch your link in explorer.
3. use this Firefox plugin makes it possible to use (host) ActiveX controls in Firefox - http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/
4. instead of ActiveX try using **Netscape Plugin Application Programming Interface (NPAPI)** - a cross-platform plugin architecture used by many web browsers.
5. Similar as with a batch file, you may create a link file to the page you need using the ".website" file extension with IE, which is [configured in windows by default to open with ie](https://fileinfo.com/extension/website). Put it in your webserver public folder and then add a link to that file in your website

Comment: How to make a bat file executed?

Comment: NPAPI is no longer supported in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write code to create a custom protocol handler in Windows.  See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx) for how to define one in the registry.

Answer (score -1):

You can use User agent switcher for chrome or firefox 
For Chrome : 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

For Firefox : 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/uaswitcher/