# Can I Open an IE window from Chrome or Firefox Window

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I want to open an IE window from chrome or firefox browser.
How can I do it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open IE browser in Firefox/Chrome page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070744/open-ie-browser-in-firefox-chrome-page)

Answer (score 2):

Without having each of your users installing a plugins/extension to either or both IE, firefox/chrome, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab-2-ff-36/?src=api
```