# URI url with "&" not coping complete

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, url, registry, uri

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744149/launch-ie-from-a-link-in-chrome#) post, I've managed to get this to work but whenever I pass an URL with an "&" on it, the link doesn't came all the way complete to IE.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/products/products.asp?N=200063&Ne=500955&ref=foo%2Cbar&Cn=Accessories
```

And in IE I'm getting:

```
http://www.example.com/products/products.asp?N=200063
```

i.e. the address till the first "&".

If someone of you guys could help me It'll be great.

Thanks!

Comment: What if you try to escape the `&`s like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27960888/1745064)? `^&`

Comment: In your example, `http://www.example.com/products/products.asp?N=200063^&Ne=500955`...

Comment: It doesn't works :( @thiagowfx I'm sailing the deepest webs for an answer