# how to disable alert this link needs to be opened with an application

Tags: firefox, registry

how to remove the alert that ask to open link in other application?
[this alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zDlG.jpg)

i followed [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744149/launch-ie-from-a-link-in-chrome/53371141#53371141) and it works fine
but i want to know how can i remove alert and just open IE directly like the default option of windows10 (microsoft-edge:url(it ask nothing from user and just open the edge browser with url))

Answer (score 0):

From your description, It looks like you want to use Internet Explorer as your default browser.

Here I assume that you are using Windows 10 OS.

You can follow steps below to make Internet Explorer as a default browser.

(1) Open **Settings** in Windows 10.

(2) Go to Apps and click on it.

(3) Select **Default apps** option.

(4) Find a category for **Web browser**.

(5) Click on the **web browser**, It will show you the option for Internet Explorer.

(6) Select **IE** and set it as **default app** for web browsing.

[image]

Reference:

[Change your default browser in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028606/windows-10-change-your-default-browser)

In the same dialog, For choosing the app. you can choose the app and check the check box to **remember** your choice may also help you to remove this dialog.

[image]

Comment: i linked the stack that i followed and as you can see in that, what i try to do is to open ie from other browser and i did something with registry
and as i describe in my question i'm trying to make something in windows 10 that open edge with special href protocol

Comment: I try to find but I did not get any way suppress the dialog for choosing the application to open the link. As a work around, you can try to check the checkbox to remember your choice may help you to avoid this dialog in future.