# Launching popup window in IE from chrome on menu click using Chrome IE Tab extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, cross-browser, popupwindow

I have a modern application where some of the menus will open a legacy application in a popup window.

This Legacy application will only works with IE as it has dependency on ActiveX.

I am looking for the possibility to launch the popup windows in IE from chrome browser on a menu click.

I have seen Chrome IE tab extension. I am looking for the possibility to use this extension to open the pop-up in IE from chrome browser itself through JavaScript logic for seamless user experience .

I have gone through the below links.But am looking for a solution without changing the registry files.

[Launch IE from a link in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744149/launch-ie-from-a-link-in-chrome)

[Open IE browser in Firefox/Chrome page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070744/open-ie-browser-in-firefox-chrome-page?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to interact with IE tab extension using JavaScript code to open the specific links in IE by itself from Chrome.

At present, It is better to use MS Edge (EDGE HTML) browser. Which has **Enterprise mode**.

If you have specific websites and apps that have compatibility problems with Microsoft Edge, you can use the Enterprise Mode site list so that the websites open in Internet Explorer 11 automatically.

References:

(1) [Interoperability and enterprise mode guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/group-policies/interoperability-enterprise-guidance-gp)

(2) [Use Enterprise Mode to improve compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/emie-to-improve-compatibility)

The new [MS Edge (Chromium) browser](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/) is ready to download. Currently it is in the preview stage and available for most of the Windows and MAC OS. In future, It will have a IE mode which lets you to visit legacy sites.

(3) [Introducing Internet Explorer mode for seamless enterprise compatibility](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/05/06/edge-chromium-build-2019-pwa-ie-mode-devtools/#60F6ICsbmIrTzJ4Q.97)

Comment: @deepal-MSFT Does it support IE5 compatibility?. Because our legacy application has X-UA-Compatible tags set to IE 5 .

Comment: Looks like you are not using Windows 10 and you are not available with MS Edge (Edge HTML) correct me if I misunderstood. If that's the case than you need to wait till MS Edge (Chromium) get officially launch.Also IE 5 is too old version. You should move to IE 11. Let us know which OS you are using currently.

Comment: We are using Windows 10. But when we see in edge available compatability modes it's not listed out IE5

Comment: Generally after setting the Enterprise mode you not need to set any other setting. It will open the page in IE by itself if page is not compatible with MS Edge. I suggest you to make a test and let us know about the result may help to narrow down the issue.