# javascript window.open should open some urls in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a situation where-in I have to open some urls in internet explorer. By default, the user can be browsing a page on chrome or edge or firefox. However, if certain links on the page are opened, it should open it in internet explorer since those pages depend upon the functionality of some IE related features. How do we fo this in javascript?

Comment: Been asked plenty of times and the simple answer is no.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by Brad, for more example you can refer this thread link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744149/launch-ie-from-a-link-in-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you don't get to choose what browser is opened.  The only thing you can do is register a protocol handler on the computer, and use that protocol.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-ph-install-registration

For example, you might register something like:

```
internet-explorer://https://example.com
```

And then rather than using `window.open()` (which probably won't work), just link to this URL.

Comment: I wonder how many people are going to blindly copy the code here over time and say "it does not work" :)

Comment: @epascarello Probably a lot.  :-)

Comment: Thanks @Brad... this would involve registering the handler on all enduser machines... just wondering - do we have anything that can be set at the webserver that tells the client to open the url in IE?

Comment: @pranag Correct, you would need your users to install your handler, possibly through a simple script or something.  No, there's absolutely nothing you can do from the web server end, or on-page, to trigger the site to open in Internet Explorer.  It's the user's choice what browser to use.  Maybe if you require IE for some things, you should prompt the user to switch, since you can detect what browser they're using.

Comment: got it working by following the steps given in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN which gives a step by step implementation for protocol handlers