# Adding to the Windows Registry

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, registry

In the following stackoverflow post;
[launch-ie-from-a-link-in-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744149/launch-ie-from-a-link-in-chrome)
part of the provided solution required an update to the Windows registry as follows;

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   alert
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "iexplore.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = cmd /k set myvar=%1 & call set myvar=%%myvar:alert:=%% & call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %%myvar%% & exit /B
```

I've never updated the registry before and I've heard that doing so wrongly can cause serious and unrecoverable situations, I'm just too scared to experiment with it for that reason. Would anyone be willing to write out a step-by-step process to accomplish this?

Many thanks,
Tim.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of language the code you providing is. But I know it is creating a protocol handler.

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` represents `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes` in the registry. Then it news a key which name is **alert**, then news two string values under alert: **(Default)** value with data **"URL:Alert Protocol"** and **URL Protocol** value with data **""**. The final result of this step is like this:

[image]

It is the same with the rest of the codes. If you're afraid to modify the registry wrongly, you could use the following reg file. The outcome is the same with the code you providing. Save below code as a **reg file**, then double click it to make it work in registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\alert]
"URL Protocol"="\"\""
@="\"URL:Alert Protocol\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\alert\DefaultIcon]
@="\"iexplore.exe,1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\alert\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\alert\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\alert\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /k set myvar=%1 & call set myvar=%%myvar:alert:=%% & call \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" %%myvar%% & exit /B"
```

Comment: Thank you, Yu Zhou ... Windows "accepted" the reg. edits ... I voted for your answer as the solution, but I have insufficient reputation points for the vote to show publicly (just FYI).

Comment: You could refer to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about how to accept an answer.