# Open URL in another browser (Firefox, IE ) using a HTML page which is in chrome.I tried doing using html code

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, automation

```
<html>
<a href="google.com">Click</a>
</html>
```

I tried using Javascript/Python.How can i do it with any other language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open IE browser in Firefox/Chrome page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070744/open-ie-browser-in-firefox-chrome-page)

Comment: visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070744/open-ie-browser-in-firefox-chrome-page

Comment: Hey Chilarai thanks for your references ...but I want to know how can I code and do it these example does not work for me.

Comment: I tried the windows registry method too but it didn't work for me